Different timbre per voice
I'm trying to tabulate a finger picked guitar piece in Guitar Pro 8. The bass is played with the thumb and is palm muted; the melody with the fingers and is not muted. I'm using two voices in the one track to get the bass and the melody on the same staff. I can't however find a way to get the bass voice muted and the melody voice not muted. I am new to Guitar Pro. Any help would be appreciated.
I am currently working around the problem by copying the bass and melody parts to separate tracks and muting (turning off the sound) the combined track.

Have you checked the manual? I've never used Guitar Pro, but a short research led me to the manual of version 7, which shows that there should be some wizard in the "Tools menu" that allows to set palm mute options, including which strings have palm muting within a range of bars or notes.

If you're using two voices on one staff, you can exclusively palm mute one voice and not the other.
For example, on the attached screenshot:

I selected voice 1
I highlighted the whole bar
I selected "P.M."
I selected voice 2
I highlighted the whole bar
I selected "let ring"

The playback plays voice 1 palm-muted and voice 2 rings out.


I'm not expert with Guitar Pro.  But I suspect than, in common with other notation software, it allows just one sound per track.  You can change over to another sound, but it's only one sound at a time.
